# I have two branches and two heads in Mercurial repo: normal or bad?

Tags: mercurial

My repo has two branches: default and stable. I probably messed up somewhere. I am seeing two heads. Is this normal?

Here are the heads:

```
changeset:   10:b4131c44f968
branch:      stable
tag:         tip
parent:      8:f06486c8c9f1
parent:      9:135102b0cb32
user:        nobody nobody <nobody@nobody.org>
date:        Mon Apr 29 00:08:57 2013 -0400
summary:     Merged with development on #2

changeset:   9:135102b0cb32
parent:      7:cf9ae7e052dd
parent:      8:f06486c8c9f1
user:        nobody nobody <nobody@nobody.org>
date:        Mon Apr 29 00:08:20 2013 -0400
summary:     BUG: Working on #2 gallery width/height not set.
```

Here is the graphlog.

```
nobody@nobody:~/hg/project-js-backup$ hg log -G
o    changeset:   10:b4131c44f968
|\   branch:      stable
| |  tag:         tip
| |  parent:      8:f06486c8c9f1
| |  parent:      9:135102b0cb32
| |  user:        nobody nobody <nobody@nobody.org>
| |  date:        Mon Apr 29 00:08:57 2013 -0400
| |  summary:     Merged with development on #2
| |
| @  changeset:   9:135102b0cb32
|/|  parent:      7:cf9ae7e052dd
| |  parent:      8:f06486c8c9f1
| |  user:        nobody nobody <nobody@nobody.org>
| |  date:        Mon Apr 29 00:08:20 2013 -0400
| |  summary:     BUG: Working on #2 gallery width/height not set.
| |
o |  changeset:   8:f06486c8c9f1
|\|  branch:      stable
| |  parent:      6:c8a92230bc6c
| |  parent:      7:cf9ae7e052dd
| |  user:        nobody nobody <nobody@nobody.org>
| |  date:        Sun Apr 28 23:14:37 2013 -0400
| |  summary:     Merged with devleopment branch. Fixed #1 data reporting double /beta in url.
| |
| o  changeset:   7:cf9ae7e052dd
| |  parent:      5:7582497d8a1b
| |  user:        nobody nobody <nobody@nobody.org>
| |  date:        Sun Apr 28 23:09:11 2013 -0400
| |  summary:     BUG: Fixed issue #1.
| |
o |  changeset:   6:c8a92230bc6c
|/   branch:      stable
|    user:        nobody nobody <nobody@nobody.org>
|    date:        Tue Apr 23 13:26:23 2013 -0400
|    summary:     Created branch stable
|
o  changeset:   5:7582497d8a1b
|  user:        nobody <nobody@nobody.org>
|  date:        Mon Apr 22 17:54:43 2013 -0300
|  summary:     Fixed result should return 200 not 201.
|
o  changeset:   4:69ddb4892fc7
|  user:        nobody <nobody@nobody.org>
|  date:        Mon Apr 22 17:49:50 2013 -0300
|  summary:     Fixed response.status on line 272.
|
o  changeset:   3:b029e0a90db8
|  user:        nobody <nobody@nobody.org>
|  date:        Mon Apr 22 17:48:18 2013 -0300
|  summary:     get rid of response_ok check in other functions.
|
o  changeset:   2:9dbccc12d211
|  user:        nobody <nobody@nobody.org>
|  date:        Mon Apr 22 17:28:01 2013 -0300
|  summary:     get rid of response_ok check in postCreateResult
|
o  changeset:   1:517b642f7785
|  user:        nobody nobody <nobody@nobody.org>
|  date:        Mon Apr 22 16:05:53 2013 -0400
|  summary:     Initialized ged.js
|
o  changeset:   0:b7eb08ae529a
   user:        nobody <nobody@nobody.org>
   date:        Mon Apr 22 13:04:36 2013 -0700
   summary:     Initial commit
```

If I need to merge, I tried combining them with (base on this http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/how-to-fix-multiple-heads/1698#1698)

```
hg up -C -r 10
hg merge -r 9
```

but I get `abort: merging with a working directory ancestor has no effect`.

Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely normal when you use two branches. Each *branch* has just one head and that means that there's nothing more to merge. Use

```
$ hg heads default
$ hg heads stable
```

to double-check this. You'll also notice that `hg merge` reports that there is nothing to merge: it will only look for a second head on your current branch.

Using two branches allow you to divide the changesets in your repository into two sets: the stable ones and the default ones. You make bugfixes on the `stable` branch (thus creating more stable changesets). You then merge `stable` into `default` to propagate the bugfix back to the `default` branch where your main development lives. Please see [Mercurial's wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching) for more info. My [guide to named branches](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/tasks/) might also be useful.